# Clicking an item in List View in Android

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to create a code to click on a list view item and display a string with the information from the text view. However, I keep just getting the value that happens to be at the top of the list (the top of the screen) when I click on the screen anywhere. Could someone tell me whats going on here and how I could correct it?

Row Item XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="itemClick" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my java code

```
public class SavedLocationsListTest extends ListActivity{

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_main);



        Intent intent = getIntent();

        displayList();

    }

    public void displayList(){

        Cursor cursor=db.getAllLocationsCursor();

        String from [] = new String[] {db.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, db.COLUMN_LOCATION};
        int to [] = new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2};



        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, cursor, from, to, 0);


        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



    }

    public void itemClick(View view){



        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        String test_string = test.getText().toString();
        Toast please_wait_for_value_msg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        please_wait_for_value_msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 250);
        please_wait_for_value_msg.show();

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you always getting "Large Text" value?

Comment: How do you set your event listener? Also, do you want to allow the user to click anywhere in the row? Or do you require them to click on the `TextView` itself.

Comment: I would get what ever the value at the top of the screen was. for example if my list was showing (in a collumn) 1,2,3,4,5 i would get 1. if my list was 2,3,4,5,6 (like if I scrolled down some past 1) I would get 2

Comment: the user only has to click on the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in itemClick here:

```
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

You are referencing a view in the activity when you call `findViewById`

You probably want to call:

```
 TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

although, that is only if the entire ListView item is clickable. If not and a button in the view is being clicked, then you need some kind of logic to determine which view like looping through your cursor and doing a comparison. There are many options, but I think this answer will get you going in the right direction.

The method "findViewById" uses the Android resource file "R" to find objects that you have defined in XML. Your original called was equivalent to:

```
 TextView test = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

where "this" was referring to the Activity. The method "itemClick" was providing a reference to the clicked ListView item as the parameter "view" - which is the ListView row that was touched.

Comment: Most likely the call to `findViewById()` here is superfluous since the `view` **is** the `TextView` that the OP is searching for. A simple cast would be more efficient. Of course, I am assuming that `itemClick()` is set in the `onClick` attribute of the `TextView` in some XML layout file

Comment: TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1) worked perfect. I'm sure there's more efficient ways to do this, but for the moment this is working. I'll experiment with this more. Can I ask: what is adding view in the front doing differently again?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write your onItemclick() method inside the adapter class so that particular item from getView() method will be selected accurately

// inside adapter class

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_list, parent,
                false);



    TextView test = (TextView)convertView. findViewById(R.id.textView1);





    test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String test_string = test.getText().toString();
    Toast please_wait_for_value_msg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    please_wait_for_value_msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 250);
    please_wait_for_value_msg.show();

        }
    });

           return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You want to click the item and get the clicked item's `textView1`, right? Maybe you should try this code(after `lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);`):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                //You could use two method to get the clicked item info.
                //1. use click view
                TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                String test_string = test.getText().toString();
                //2. use cursor
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) dataAdapter.getItem(position);
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(db.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to your problem depending on the exact behavior you want:

1. If you want to allow the user to click anywhere in the row of your list, you should override [`onListItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)). This method receives a `View` parameter for the row which was clicked. You can use it to access the `TextView` from that particular row.
2. If you only want the action to occur when the user clicks on the `TextView` itself, you can use the code you have with a small change: use the `View` parameter which is passed into the `itemClick()` method. This is the `TextView` which was clicked on, so you can cast it to a `TextView` and get the `String` from it.